# Как сделать сохранение состояние WebView НЕ при повороте экрана,а при возврате после закрытия приложения?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, webview, android-webview

Я захожу в WebView , допустим,на яндекс. Потом иду на почту в отдел регистрации. Закрываю приложение через панель задач и снова открываю - вижу что нахожусь на первоначальном url.Как сделать сохранения состояния WebView? И вообще надо сделать также загрузку файлов и оплату по WebView,где можно подробно ознакомиться с этим,а то на просторах рунета только ответы на вопросы как исправить сохранение данных при повороте экрана.В общем, как сделать сохранения сессии?

Answer (score 0):

Замени

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("**SHA256**");`
```

на

```
MessageDigest.getInstance(**"SHA-256"**);
```

Comment: @Sergei Buvaka к сожалению я перепутал и не туда ответил, удалите если можно

Comment: Вы можете сами удалить ваш ответ. Я этого сделать не могу

Answer (score 0):

Ну все что касается "сохранить после закрытия приложения" это сохранить на устройство состояние и при открытии вашей WebView это состояние восстанавливать.

Тут у вас 3 варианта в целом:

1. Если данные достаточно просты (например только ссылка) то используйте [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences).
2. Если что-то более сложное то скорее всего вам стоит создать базу данных. Тут либо используйте [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite), либо что более просто и эффективнее - подключите [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).
3. Можете еще сохранить на устройство в файл. Не думаю, что вам нужно именно это, но в целом вы можете использовать и этот способ.

Других способов хранить что-либо после выгрузки приложения из памяти насколько я знаю нет (ну или они совсем неочевидны)